# When I start my spring server, I get a 404 when accessing the url in my browser or postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I start my Spring server, I see this in the logs: `Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9002 (http)`. So, I get the impression that it will by run locally on port 9002. If use my browser to go to this url http://localhost:9002/, then I get a 404. I'll also try to send a POST based on this endpoint in the spring code

```
@ApiOperation(value = "GET a List of Messages")
@GetMapping(value = "/msg", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity getMessageList(HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<MessageVo> result = msgService.getMessageList(request.getQueryString());
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When I post to http://localhost:9002/msg, I also get a 404. Any work arounds why it's not displaying correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing context name in your URL.
`http://localhost:9002/<context>/msg`

Answer (score 0):

Try posting request to the below  URL :-

```
http://localhost:9002/msg
```

Comment: sorry, I meant to type that originally in my question. I've already tried that

Comment: This is a GET end point, try accessing http://localhost:9002/msg from browser

Comment: Still get a 404

Comment: could you show complete code of controller class. Also, did you set server.port to 9002?

Comment: Also, show your properties file if you have added some properties